# How to center divs on page

Tags: css, html

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/H4F8H/16/

I'm attempting to center two divs by wrapping an outer div and centering it :

```
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
```

But the divs are remaining left aligned. How can I center these divs on page ?

fiddle code :

HTML :

```
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<div id="block">
<img height="50" style="max-width: 50px;background-position: top left;" src="http://socialmediababe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/administrator.jpg" />


<div style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">
Test
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>

</div>

<div id="block">
<img height="50" style="max-width: 50px;background-position: top left;" src="http://socialmediababe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/administrator.jpg" />


<div style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">
Test
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#block { 
    margin-right:100px;
    border-width: 2px; 
    border-color: #4682B4; 
    background-color: WHITE; 
    width: 100px; 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height:30px;
    padding:3px 0;
    float:left;
}
img{
float:left;
}
#block:hover {
  background-color: #C2DFFF ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is a block level element by default so it will take up 100% of horizontal space if you do not assign some `width` to it, so you need to assign some `width` to your container

```
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; width: 300px;">
```

Here, you can just set the width accordingly. Also avoid using `inline` CSS.

Your CSS is lil sloppy, for example `margin-right:100px;` is not required, also, you can use shorthand like

`margin: 0 auto;` = `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H4F8H/28/) (Added a red border just to show the boundaries)

Note: You are floating your elements, so make sure you clear your floats either by using `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` which I've already done in the demo provided, else you can also use the snippet below to self clear the parent like

```
.clear:after {
   display: table;
   clear: both;
   content: "";
}
```

Comment: I use 'margin-right:100px;' to create a space between each of the divs so is required ?

Comment: @user470184 you should take a look at `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

A couple things I want to point out in this post:

1. You have set `Id="block"` in two different instances. Id's are meant to be unique. If you want a reusable identifier you should be using classes.
2. Inline styling should be avoided when possible. In this case there is no need to set inline styling on the parent div.

There is more then one way to center div's
I am going to leave this link here: http://thenewcode.com/723/Seven-Ways-of-Centering-With-CSS

This would be my solution:

html:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="block">
    <span>Test</span>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <span>Test 2</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  background: grey;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give  a width to that container.

```
#outerdiv{
margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center">
   <!-- -staff ->
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to look up what deprecated means. It works, however it is no longer considered the proper way to implement the function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

Comment: Yes I know that, but I am still using it : )

Answer (score 0):

`margin:auto;` doesn't work unless the width is specified...

```
<div style="margin:auto;width:100px;">

your content here. [Replace the width with your choice]

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Giving width and margin auto will centralise the content in specified width.

```
 <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:400px;">//give variable width here..Normally 1000 to 1018..
<div id="block">
<img height="50" style="max-width: 50px;background-position: top left;" src="http://socialmediababe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/administrator.jpg" />


<div style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">
Test
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>

</div>

<div id="block">
<img height="50" style="max-width: 50px;background-position: top left;" src="http://socialmediababe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/administrator.jpg" />


<div style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">
Test
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: those who are giving downvotes please state the reason for that.

Answer (score -1):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H4F8H/27/)**

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid red;

}
```